# Pandas Dataframe - Adding new row based on variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that sorts through a large series of data and pulls a bunch of necessary values and saves them as numbers or strings.

How do I then place those values into a new `dataframe`?

For instance:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=labels)
```

Now I want to add variables x, y, Z and the text "banana" to the DataFrame into A, B, C and D respectively.

Is there a line of code using an append-like method or something similar that will do this quickly and efficiently?

(My actual `dataframe` will have a multitude of columns, so a quick script is much more useful than creating an empty `dataframe` and changing each cell value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you, if I understand correctly:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['x', 'y', 'Z', 'banana']

>>> df
   A  B  C       D
0  x  y  Z  banana
```

Or, more conveniently, as a function:

```
def insert_row(df, my_row):
    df.loc[len(df)] = my_row

insert_row(df, ['x', 'y', 'Z', 'banana'])
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I am looking for as it will add the next row to the database. If it's empty - it will add row zero, and if it has 6 current entries, it will add the 7th to row 6. Thanks.

Also - if I have variables, X and Y as strings, I just place df.loc[len(df)0 = [X,Y, 'Z', 'banana']?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: `X = 'string1'`, `Y = 'string2'`, `df.loc[len(df)] = [X, Y, 'Z', 'banana']` works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

In [3]: df.loc[0] = ["x", "y", "Z", "banana"]

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   A  B  C       D
0  x  y  Z  banana
```